# Change SharePoint language based on current user's country

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, language, language-pack

Any ideas how to change the current SharePoint language based on the current user's country?

Appreciate any suggestions,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is controlled via User Profile > Language and Region Settings. Each user can change it themselves manually. Please note that as an Admin you must allow users to change their locale in their profiles themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how admin allow users to change their profiles and  is there any custom solution to check current user country and apply language setting using code